# Two identical particles of mass $m$ travel towards each other at speed $v$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, conservation-laws, collision

> Two identical particles of mass $m$ travel towards each other at speed $v$; they combine and form a single new particle.  By employing conservation of momentum and conservation of energy, what is the mass of this new particle in
>   terms of $m$ and $v$?
>
> They are meant to be combined with relativistic expressions for momentum and kinetic energy.

Now, I was thinking using $p=\gamma m_0v $, & using KE = $(\gamma - 1)mc^2$.
In reference frame of first particle (call it A), $v= 0, m = m_a + m_b?$ (I am not sure how these two actually combine. They're identical so they have the same mass, but taking it from the reference frame of A would that make their masses different? $v_b' = \frac{v-u}{1-\frac{uv}{c^2}}$? Would $u$ just be $v$? And how would the velocities combine? I am completely befuddled on this one.

Comment: The questions you are asking about mass are the kind of struggle that you only encounter if you think in terms of "relativistic mass". The better way to formulate special relativity defines mass (the only mass!) as the Lorentz invariant square are the  momentum four vector. Then you just work the problem by conservation of the four-momentum.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what would be the mass of the newly formed particle? It would be simply $2\gamma m$.

**Reason:** Assume the mass of the newly formed particle is $M$. From symmetry, the newly formed particle will be at rest. Thus, the momentum conservation is trivially followed. For the energy conservation to be followed, we require that the total energy associated with the newly formed particle be the same as the sum of the energies associated with the initial two particles. 
i.e., $Mc^2 = 2\gamma mc^2$. Thus, $M=2\gamma m$.

Now, how to reach the same result using the frame of reference attached with any one of the particles? Well, you can't- at least if you don't know how to do Physics in non-inertial frames. Because, during the collision, each of the particles experiences an acceleration (actually a variable acceleration) and thus it becomes difficult to analyze things from any one of the particle's frame. Rather, one can easily analyze everything from the initial inertial frame from which one was observing the two particles to have uniform velocities $v$ and $-v$ respectively.